# Workflow for making edits to Python package?

Tags: python

I'd like to add a few features to a package (https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/lightning), but am unsure of the proper approach, especially since much of the source is in Cython.

From other posts, I've gathered that for making package edits, I want to start by either using pip and install in edit mode to a new directory or clone the source from git and make edits there. After that though, I'm a little lost. Do I make my changes, run setup.py, and test my new changes? What if I need to make another edit, so I just edit the existing code and rerun setup.py?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted to the [scikit-learn mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/scikit-learn-general), not here.

Comment: If you `python setup.py develop`, you don't need to re-run every time you change something.

Comment: This question isn't specific to scikit-learn - I linked it because I thought the Cython component might have an effect on the answer.

How would 'python setup.py develop' work with needing to build/install the dev version (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/lightning#installation))

Answer (score 1):

Many possible answers to this one.  My preference is to clone the source into a directory, create a symbolic link to the python module folder, and include the symbolic link in my PYTHONPATH environment variable.